# Ubuntu Software Center states ''No network connection" in reviews, but internet available elsewhere

Tags: networking, internet

My computer is connected to the internet via mobile broadband. But when opening Ubuntu Software Center and want to read reviews it says `no network connection, connect to the internet to see more reviews` although I can install application without problem.

Comment: Check your software sources ( Edit -> Software Sources...")

Comment: i did that before, but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

What if you directly browse to the underlying URL, e.g. http://reviews.ubuntu.com/reviews/api/1.0/reviews/filter/en/any/any/any/ubuntu-edu-tertiary/ ?

Comment: better if it would be working inside the app rather than going to the web then come back to software center for installation

Comment: I was not suggesting that this is your permanent solution, rather a way to find out if that URL is somehow inaccessible from your computer (a DNS issue, bad proxy, etc).